# How to add new section to shopify page after .liquid file has been created

Tags: shopify, liquid

I just created a new shopify section called `how-it-works.liquid`.  I am going into the `customize theme` menu and press `add section`, but the new section is not there even though the file exists in the sections folder.  How do you add a section to the section list once the file is created?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to dynamically add the section to your homepage, you need to specify the [preset](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-use-sections#presets) attribute in your section settings.

If you're missing your section on a specific page then you probably have not added it to the template:

```
{% section "how-it-works-or-whatever" -%}
```